# I got error "packages have unmet dependencies" while Installing Mysql in EC2 Ubuntu:

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I try to install mysql on ec2 ubuntu-xenial-16.04. When I try to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I got an error like:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-5.13.0-1028-aws : Depends: linux-aws-5.13-headers-5.13.0-1028 but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-8.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: This command `sudo apt-get install -f` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command `sudo apt-get install -f` solved my problem.

Comment: why did this solve your problem? what does the `-f` flag do? i assume it's "force" but why would forcing a package to be installed fix the dependency issue? I'd think that forcing would just ignore the dependencies. Could you add some more explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Update the repo

```bash
sudo apt-get update
```

Install mysql-server with the missing dependencies

```bash
sudo apt-get install -f mysql-server
```

Comment: thanks for answer. tried but same

Comment: why try that? what does it do? how does it solve the issue?